# Sitecore EXM broken link in the mail message

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1, sitecore-ecm

I've created "Simple HTML message" and added some internal links in the Message body using rich text editor

In html it look like this:

```html
<a href="~/link.aspx?_id=D16025CAB7D049FDAC6863C29C13F0C1&amp;_z=z">TEST</a>
```

When I sending test message this link is converted to: `http:mydomain.com/://mydomain.com/TEST`

This link is broken, redundant part - `://mydomain.com/`

How I can fix it?

LinkManager.config

```xml
<add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="never" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="true" siteResolving="true" patch:source="LinkManager.config"/>
```

Sites.config:

```xml
<site name="Website3" targetHostName="site1.mydomain.com" hostName="site1.mydomain.com" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/site1.mydomain.com" startItem="/home" language="en" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="25MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" patch:source="Sites.config"/>
<site name="Website2" targetHostName="site2.mydomain.com" hostName="site2.mydomain.com" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/site2.mydomain.com" startItem="/home" language="en" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="25MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" patch:source="Sites.config"/>
<site name="Website1" targetHostName="mydomain.com" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/www.mydomain.com" startItem="/home" language="en" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="50MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="25MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" patch:source="Sites.config"/>
```

Comment: What is your BaseUrl on your EXM Manager root?

Comment: Base url is http:// mydomain.com
But this value does not affect to the generated link. I can change it on standard value http:// your.host and as a result in the mail I see:  http:// mydomain.com/:// mydomain.com/TEST

Comment: double check that the link goes to the path /sitecore/redirecturlpage.aspx first. You should have something like this - yourfulldomain/sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_contact_id=A327FF7E277E88F06093DAF0FEF65944&ec_message_id=1359DB9B9C364ABBA92C5A4872980F9B&ec_url=%2f%7e%2flink.aspx%3f_id%3d6EE48D4FEB034DA09A5ADEB41D8D46B7%26_z%3dz

Comment: If the you are sending a test message through the review tab, you will not see the link that Ian referred. The sending test message pipeline doesn't render the url. It must be something else. Which version of Sitecore and EXM are you testing?

Comment: Yes, I'm sending test message. Sitecore version 8.1 Update 3 - Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160519). Email Experience Manager 3.3.0 rev. 160527

Comment: Long shot - have any settings changed with your linkManager in your Sitecore.config that are not default?

Comment: LinkManger config: <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="never" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="true" siteResolving="true" patch:source="LinkManager.config"/>

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful too, I've added Sites.config to the first post

Comment: I found place with issue - it HandleInternalLink processor.

This line return absolute path  

args.Url = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(new ItemUtilExt().GetItem(result.ItemId), defaultUrlOptions);
despite the fact that defaultUrlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = false;

For testing I copied this code in rendering which placed on the home page and result was correct relative path instead absolute

Any ideas how I can fix it in the HandleInternalLink processor?